# I want to pattern match from Array of String with a single String in scala?

Tags: scala

```
val aggFilters = Array["IR*","IR_"] 
val aggCodeVal = "IR_CS_BPV"
val flag = compareFilters(aggFilters,aggCodeVal)
```

As per my requirement I want to compare the patterns given in the aggFilters  with aggCodeVal. The first pattern "IR*" is a match with "IR_CS_BPV" but not the second one, hence I want to break out of the for loop after the match is found so that I don't go for the second one "IR_". I don't want to use break statement like java.

```
  def compareFilters(aggFilters: Array[String], aggCodeVal: String): Boolean = {
    var flag: Boolean = false
    for (aggFilter <- aggFilters) {
      if (aggFilter.endsWith("*")
          && aggCodeVal.startsWith(aggFilter.substring(0, aggFilter.length() - 1))) {
        flag = true
      }
      else if (aggFilter.startsWith("*")
               && aggCodeVal.startsWith(aggFilter.substring(1, aggFilter.length()))) {
        flag = true
      }
      else if (((aggFilter startsWith "*")
                && aggFilter.endsWith("*"))
               && aggCodeVal.startsWith(aggFilter.substring(1, aggFilter.length() - 1))) {
        flag = true
      }
      else if (aggFilter.equals(aggCodeVal)) {
        flag = true
      }
      else {
        flag = false
      }
    }
    flag
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `*` is your only wild-card character, you should be able to leverage `Regex` to do your match testing.

```
def compareFilters(aggFilters: Array[String], aggCodeVal: String): Boolean = 
 aggFilters.exists(f => s"$f$$".replace("*",".*").r.findAllIn(aggCodeVal).hasNext)
```

Comment: not working.. compareFilter(Array("IR_","ABC*"),"IR_ABC") is returning true but it should return false.

Comment: That's because the pattern `ABC*` matches the last 3 characters of your target string.  The wild-card `*` is taken to mean "zero or more extra characters".  If you need it to mean "one or more extra characters" then change the `replace()` from `.*` to `.+`.  If, on the other hand, it is supposed to return `false` because the target string doesn't _start_ with `ABC` then change the regex to `"^$f$$"`.

Comment: With the limited examples provided, I wasn't sure what the exact requirements were for the pattern matching, but the `Regex` library is pretty flexible so it can probably be adjusted to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `exists` method to do it for you.

Extract a function that compares a *single* filter, with this signature:

```
def compareFilter(aggFilter: String, aggCodeVal: String): Boolean
```

And then:

```
def compareFilters(aggFilters: Array[String], aggCodeVal: String): Boolean = {
  aggFilters.exists(filter => compareFilter(filter, aggCodeVal))
}
```

The implementation of `compareFilter`, BTW, can be shortened to something like:

```
def compareFilter(aggFilter: String, aggCodeVal: String): Boolean = {
  (aggFilter.startsWith("*") && aggFilter.endsWith("*") && aggCodeVal.startsWith(aggFilter.drop(1).dropRight(1))) ||
  (aggFilter.endsWith("*") && aggCodeVal.startsWith(aggFilter.dropRight(1))) ||
  (aggFilter.startsWith("*") && aggCodeVal.startsWith(aggFilter.drop(1))) ||
  aggFilter.equals(aggCodeVal)
}
```

But - double check me on that one, not sure I followed your logic perfectly.